# Is there a way to dynamically change log name at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I currently am writing to a statically named log file as defined in my serilog config:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="%LOCALAPPDATA%\App_Data\Logs\StaticallyNamedLog.log" />
```

I'd like to be able to change the logfile name at runtime i.e.

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="%LOCALAPPDATA%\App_Data\Logs\{appname}-Log.log" />
```

In log4net for example I'd set a log4net global property value for "appname" in code before the settings were read in.

```
log4net.globalContext.properties["appname"] = "App1"
log4net.config.xmlConfigurator.configure("log4net.config")
```

Then in the logfile I'd reference it like so

```
%property{appname}
```

This would then get substituted into this path.

How can I do the equivalent in Serilog? I've done a lot of searching but can't find anything on this specific problem.
Thanks